# Undefined local variable or method `login_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, integration-testing, minitest

I'm doing some integration testing in rails for a sessions controller and in the test I get that my `login_path` is not defined even though it is defined in the `routes.rb` file and when I invoke that path in the console it also shows up. Any idea what's causing this?

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'

  root             'static_pages#home'
  get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'

  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
end
```

test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  get login_path
  assert_template 'sessions/new'
  post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
  assert_template 'sessions/new'
  assert_not flash.empty?
  get root_path
  assert flash.empty?
end
```

Comment: Try `rake routes` to list all the available routes in your Rails project

Comment: It's there, that's why the error makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm reading the [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing) correctly, you should call the "test" method and then pass the test code as a block. Something like this should work

```
class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "user can log in" do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, didn't notice I missed that wrapper. Thanks.